# How do I make a constructor that accepts any primitive type and converts to an int in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, int, primitive

I'm making a program where I need to declare a constructor that can accept various primitive types such as `double` or `float` and convert that to an `int`.

My program only uses `int`, so I need to accept any primitive data type in the constructor and convert it to an `int`.

Comment: So whats holding you back?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a template constructor:

```
struct Foo
{
  template <typename T>
  explicit Foo(const T& x) :i(x) {}
 private:
  int i;
};
```

Comment: Not really a criticism just a suggestion, since he said only primitives maybe you want to use [`is_fundamental`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental)

Comment: @aaronman I think [`is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) would be a better fit. no sense is converting `void` to `int` (or even trying to).

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah that would be an improvement, though I think primitive and fundamental types are the same set

Comment: @aaronman I was going to add something, bu then I thought it isn't clear whether this restriction really desired by OP. So I left it at "anything from which an `int` can be constructed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SFINAE to cause a compilation error if the type isn't able to be converted to an int like so...

```
template<class T>
MyConstructor(const T& x, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, int>::value>::type* = nullptr)
{
    int myint = static_cast<int>(x);
}
```